# How to pass base64encode string through XMLHttpRequest() post request

Tags: javascript, web-services, post, xmlhttprequest, base64

I am trying to upload a image to server,In that i have converted  image to base64encode string and i need to pass that base64encode string to webservice,that webservice convert the base64 string to file and saving in database.but base64encode string has huge length approximately(85,000) when i pass this string to webservice i am getting the following error.

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

i need to pass this by using only XMLHttpRequest() with out using the ajax,jquery  please help me.

below is  my code.

```
                    var filesToBeUploaded = document.getElementById("afile");
                        var file = filesToBeUploaded.files[0];
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function(event) {
                            var binaryStringResult = reader.result;                     

                            var binaryString =binaryStringResult.split(',')[1];
                            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xhr.open("POST","http://url/api/jsonws/Global-portlet.org_roles/add-file-entry?repositoryId=11304&folderId=0&sourceFileName=test108.jpeg&mimeType=image%2Fjpeg&title=test108.jpeg&description=test108.jpeg&changeLog=test108.jpeg&basecode64="+ binaryString);


                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","BasicbmFyYXlhbmFAdmlkeWF5dWcuY29tOnRlc3Q=");
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

                            xhr.send();

                            xhr.onload = function() {
                                alert('in sucess');

                            };
                            xhr.onerror = function(e) {
                                alert('in error');
                            };

                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) ?

Comment: Were you able to solve?

Answer (score 0):

For POST, don't include it in the URL, you need to put it in the body, i.e.

```
xhr.send(binaryString);
```

I doubt your Content-Type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded is correct in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue that you encountering here is that you are exceeding the maximum length of a query string.

What you need to do is something like the following:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://url/api/jsonws/Global-portlet.org_roles/add-file-entry";
var params = "repositoryId=11304&folderId=0&sourceFileName=test108.jpeg&mimeType=image%2Fjpeg&title=test108.jpeg&description=test108.jpeg&changeLog=test108.jpeg&basecode64="+ binaryString;
xhr.open("POST", url, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send(params);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi Oliver Ridgway,  Thanks for giving quick reply i have already tried but file is not uploaded

Comment: Try changing the Content-type to "multipart/form-data"